# Preserving spaces in string when concatenating in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble in saving spaces when concatenating a string in php.  It is meant to be used as an sql query so the spaces are important.

```
$sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM';
$sql_query .= 'table_id';
$sql_query .= 'WHERE user_id = 5';
```

and I end up getting

```
SELECT * FROMtable_idWHERE user_id = 5
```

Please note I am giving this as an example and its not the real query, I am just trying to find a general way to control the spaces when concatenating.  Thanks

Comment: Put a space at the beginning and/or end of each string . . . `'table_id '`

Comment: What about using multiline strings instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM ';
$sql_query .= 'table_id ';
$sql_query .= 'WHERE user_id = 5';
```

When you concatenate a string, it is interpreted **exactly** as you have written it. That means, PHP does **NOT** add spaces for you - you must do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You juste have to set a whitespace at the end or at the beginning of the strings. For example :

```
$sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM ';
$sql_query .= ' table_id ';
$sql_query .= ' WHERE user_id = 5 ';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include space character as part of the strings.

```
$sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM';
$sql_query .= ' table_id'; /* space is prefixed here */
$sql_query .= ' WHERE user_id = 5'; /* and here */
```

So that on concatenation they are preserved.

Final sql_query would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table_id WHERE user_id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Once possibility, if you want to automate things, is to use [implode](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.implode.php) with a space as the `$glue` parameter on an array of SQL fragments. For example:

```
$sql_fragments = array(
    'SELECT * FROM',
    'table_id',
    'WHERE user_id = 5'
);
$sql_query = implode(' ', $sql_fragments);
```

This will be slower than concatenation but might be useful if you are building a query dynamically.

Alternately, consider using a [HEREDOC (multi-line string)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for declaring your SQL.